# SpriteKit: How to identify the previous scene the user is coming from?

Tags: sprite-kit, swift3

I have a GameOver scene with a button to a Settings scene. (**Code shown below**) I want to add a button on the MainMenu scene to do the same, send the user to the Settings scene but I want just one “Back” button on the Settings scene. I'm assuming this can be accomplished with an IF statement. If the user comes from A scene move to B else if the user comes from X scene move to Y scene.

How can I tell in SpriteKit which scene is the user coming from?

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    for touch: AnyObject in touches {

        let pointOfTouch = touch.location(in: self)

        let nodeUserTapped = atPoint(pointOfTouch)

        if nodeUserTapped.name == "BackButton" {

            let sceneToMoveTo = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameOverScene")
            let gameTransition = SKTransition.fade(withDuration: 0.5)
            self.view!.presentScene(sceneToMoveTo!, transition: gameTransition)

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case you can adopt various solutions to achieve what you wish.
I want to show you just 2 example, a rapid and simple way and a more custom way.

---

**1:** - You can use the [`userData`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/sknode/1483121-userdata) instance property of your next scene to store the current scene, something like:

```
sceneToMoveTo.userData = NSMutableDictionary()
sceneToMoveTo.userData?.setObject("MenuScene", forKey: "previousScene" as NSCopying)
```

and when you are in the next scene you can ask to this `NSMutableDictionary` who is the previous scene as:

```
guard let previousValue = self.userData?.value(forKey: "previousScene") else { return }
switch previousValue as! String {
case "MenuScene":
   //do whatever you want if the previous scene was MenuScene
default:
   break
}
```

---

**2:** - You can build an enumeration that contain a list of the scenes where you want to move.

After that, each scene contain a simple var to store the previous scene: it's default is `.None` but you should fill it when you call the new scene. When you arrive to the `SettingsScene` and press your back button you can ask to this `previousScene` var who is the previous scene and decide, through a switch statement, where to go.

```
// GAMEOVER SCENE
import SpriteKit
enum Scenes : Int {
    case MainMenu = 0
    case Settings = 1
    case GameOver = 2
    case None = 3
}
class GameOver: SKScene {
    var previousScene:Scenes = .None
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch: AnyObject in touches {
            let pointOfTouch = touch.location(in: self)
            let nodeUserTapped = atPoint(pointOfTouch)
            if nodeUserTapped.name == "settingsBtn" {
                if let sceneToMoveTo = SKScene(fileNamed: "SettingsScene") {
                    let gameTransition = SKTransition.fade(withDuration: 0.5)
                    (sceneToMoveTo as! SettingsScene).previousScene = .GameOver
                    self.view?.presentScene(sceneToMoveTo, transition: gameTransition)
                }   
            }     
        }
    }
}
// SETTINGS SCENE
import SpriteKit
class SettingsScene: SKScene {
    var previousScene:Scenes = .None
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        print("Current scene loaded: \(type(of:self))")
        print("Previous scene was: \(previousScene)")
        let label = SKLabelNode.init(text: "BackButton")
        addChild(label)
        label.position = CGPoint(x:self.frame.midX,y:self.frame.midY)
        label.name = "backBtn"
    }
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch: AnyObject in touches {
            let pointOfTouch = touch.location(in: self)
            let nodeUserTapped = atPoint(pointOfTouch)
            if nodeUserTapped.name == "backBtn" {
                switch previousScene {
                case .MainMenu: // go back to menu
                    if let sceneToMoveTo = SKScene(fileNamed: "MenuScene") {
                        let gameTransition = SKTransition.fade(withDuration: 0.5)
                        (sceneToMoveTo as! MenuScene).previousScene = .Settings
                        self.view?.presentScene(sceneToMoveTo, transition: gameTransition)
                    }
                    break
                case .GameOver: // re-launch a new game
                    print("The game was ended")
                    if let sceneToMoveTo = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {
                        let gameTransition = SKTransition.fade(withDuration: 0.5)
                        (sceneToMoveTo as! GameScene).previousScene = .Settings
                        self.view?.presentScene(sceneToMoveTo, transition: gameTransition)
                    }
                default:
                    break
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
//MENU SCENE
import SpriteKit
class MenuScene: SKScene {
    var previousScene:Scenes = .None
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        print("Current scene loaded: \(type(of:self))")
        print("Previous scene was: \(previousScene)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`userData` is your friend here, it is a dictionary that can be found on any type of `SKNode`.  All you need to do is store the current scene you are in into the `userData`, and make the transition.  This will keep your current scene in memory.  Since your current scene is in memory and is not a part of the new scenes node tree, no update method will be called on it. Essentially you have a frozen scene state.  Then when you are ready to return to the scene, just pull the instance out of the user data, and present it.  Viola, you have transitioned back to your scene the moment that you have left it previously.

Basically, if you want the scene to resume where it left off, do the following:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    for touch: AnyObject in touches {

        let pointOfTouch = touch.location(in: self)

        let nodeUserTapped = atPoint(pointOfTouch)

        if nodeUserTapped.name == "SettingButton" {

            let sceneToMoveTo = SKScene(fileNamed: "SettingScene")
            sceneToMoveTo.userData = ["previousScene":self.scene]

            let gameTransition = SKTransition.fade(withDuration: 0.5)
            self.view!.presentScene(sceneToMoveTo!, transition: gameTransition)
        }
    }
}
```

Then, at any point you want to return to the previous scene, just add the following.

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    for touch: AnyObject in touches {

        let pointOfTouch = touch.location(in: self)

        let nodeUserTapped = atPoint(pointOfTouch)

        if nodeUserTapped.name == "BackButton" {

           if let userData = self.userData, let previousScene = userData["previousScene"] as? SKScene
           {
                let gameTransition = SKTransition.fade(withDuration: 0.5)
                self.view!.presentScene(previousScene, transition: gameTransition)
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Previously I'd asked (more generally) about making custom scene transitions. Could this approach of storing a scene be used to make custom scene transitions?